# Python installation not full and python not working 3.11.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I would like to ask you for help. I have been using Python 3.8 for almost 2 years and I decided to update to 3.11. Initially everything was correct. But at some point Windows shows me that Python is being reinstalled (I don't have a message print screen ..), but from that time I cannot run Python at all on my PC.

So I tried to reinstall it several times with no success. All the time I receive this "The system cannot find the file `C:\\Users...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe.`"
But files are there:

[image]

Even when I try to run "python.exe" directly I receive this error:

[image]

System Variables are right (added it to both PATH):
**1) User Variables:**
**2) System Variables**

Strange thing is that after RE-Installing Python the "pip.exe" is missing in subfolder "Python/Scripts/" (it is simply empty).

I also found that someone advice to turn off "aliases":

[image]

I tried also Repair - no success.

**Details**:
**System**: Windows 10 (21H2)
**Python**: 3.11.0 (full 64bit installer from python.org)

- installed only for me

[image]

cmd:

[image]

This is resulting that I cannot use interpreter in VS Code and continue development. Any one Any Idea? Thank you

Jan

I tried to reinstall python, repair python, update paths in system variables, look in registry. My expectation is that python will work again.

Comment: Is your windows username CZ011845? Because that seems... unlikely? (but possible). The appdata folder screenshot you're showing does not show that username, so you might not be looking in the right folder. That said, this feels like it's time to first uninstall python (using control panel -> programs and features) for both your own account _and_ the admin account, rebooting, verifying there are no traces of it left on (appdata, path, etc), then downloading the python 3.11 installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ and installing that.

Comment: `C:\CZ011845\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe` Have you tried `cd`'ing to each of those directories to see if they all exist?